# Application front end not able to call REST API of SSO Server

Tags: angular, rest, networking, browser, single-sign-on

Our front end is in Angular and its unable to call the REST API of an SSO server in customer environment (to get open-id configuration). I do not see any call being made in network tab. However same code works in our test environment for Okta server.

When watched the variables of subscribe method I see destination as closed for the customer environment. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

have you check for HttpClient request is correctly set up ?
also if the issue destination as closed for the customer environment still exist maybe the problem unsubscribed prematurely or there is server response causes the observable to complete.

if the issue about CORS maybe you can take a look this reference
https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/